# What to do if a random variable is apparently binomial but the amount of calculations required is too high?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

**An exercise reads like this...**

> A coin is thrown 400 times. Calculate the probability that the number
>   of faces:
>
> 1. Be greater than 200.
> 2. Be between 180 and 220.

**...and I do not know how to do so many calculations. I suppose there must be some way of calculating it more directly, perhaps with another distribution or without using one.**

Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: As the $n$ gets to be large the binomial distribution increasingly resembles the normal distribution.  This is the implication of the Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: You should already know the mean and standard deviation of a binomial random variable.

Comment: @Ian You're right! How I did not realize before? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Given you are doing your work on a computer, just use *Mathematica*:

```
Probability[x > 200, x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[400, .5]]
```

0.480065

```
Probability[180 < x < 220, x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[400, .5]]
```

0.94896

This takes 0.001496 second on a Mac.

[image]

Comment: In fact forget to put a detail in the question: This exercise is a test of the year 2009, as I am preparing for a test I will have soon. But thanks for your contribution.